# Radon-Nikodym derivative as a limit of ratios

Tags: measure-theory

This question is related to [Radon-Nikodym derivatives as limits of ratios](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154130/radon-nikodym-derivatives-as-limits-of-ratios).

Let $F$, $G$ be sigma-finite measures (or at least probability measures) on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F \ll G$.

The theorem quoted in the link tells that the Radon-Nikodym derivative checks
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}G} (x) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F(x-h, x+h)}{G(x-h, x+h)}$$
for $G$-almost every $x$.

Do we have a similar equality with one-sided balls? In other words, is the following equality 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}G} (x) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F [x, x+h)}{G [x, x+h)}$$
true for $G$-almost every $x$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I am unable to find a answer that use nicely shrinking sets when _G_ is **not** the Lebesgue measure. Is this notion defined somewhere for more general measures?

Comment: That's a good point. For example, $(x,x+h)$ also shrinks nicely, but won't work for pure point measures.

Comment: OK, the Lebesgue differentiation theorem seems to work arbitrary Radon measure _G_ and nicely shrinking sets, provided that "nicely shrinking" is defined with respect to the measure _G_, not the Lebesgue measure.
Unfortunately, finding a reference to this fact is hard. The only one I have found is in [this online supplementary material](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-105-theorem-1-21.pdf) of the book [A First Course in Sobolev Spaces](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-105). Does anybody know another reference?

Comment: So in my case, one still has to prove that for G-almost all x, there exists a constant C > 0 independent of h > 0 such that _G_ [x,x+h) > C _G_ [x-h,x+h]. 
If _x_ is a jump point of _G_, it is OK.
For (Lebesgue-)almost all continuity points, _G_'(x) exists and is the limit of _G_ [x,x+h) /h and _G_ [x-h,x+h] /(2h). But does the ratio _G_ [x,x+h) / _G_ [x-h,x+h] converges to 1/2? It would be OK if _G_'(x) were not 0 on all that points. But unfortunately that is not sure as _G_ might be singular...